# Question was WRONGLY dismissed (not closed) as "already answered"

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm referring to [this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/462261/i-or-me-at-the-end-of-a-list).  The link they dismissed it with did ***not*** answer the dismissed question.  So, how do we non-mods request that the dismissal be reversed?  (I did not post the dismissed question.)

Comment: You should edit your question to make it clear that it is not a duplicate. Editing should put it into the reopen queue. I think though that in its current state, your question doesn’t meet the quality standards, and that if it wasn’t closed as a dupe, it would be closed for other reasons. You may want to review the “How to ask” section in the [help] and include information on what steps you took to try to answer your question before you posted it.

Comment: @ColleenV:  I didn't post the question.

Comment: Sorry, I’m on my phone, tabbing around is hard. Still, you should review the [help] if you feel that particular question needs to be reopened without any improvement. The help also explains more about duplicates.

Comment: If you aren’t the OP of the closed post, and are therefore not in a position to edit it to clarify how it differs from the linked duplicate, then you should make a clear and detailed case *here*, in your meta-question, for why they differ. Without any additional argumentation, the close voters and watchers from the sidelines have no reason to dispute the original decision, as no additional material has been offered. Similarly, arguments should be made for why the Q materially differs from the other posts MetaEd linked to. This is well-trod ground. Finally: the Q shows zero evidence of research

Comment: @DanBron:  Meta only posted those links (one of them the dismissal link) after I posted this one.

Comment: @Wordster I don’t think that makes a difference? The question is either a dupe or it isn’t (it is - we’ve gotten this question and others like it scores of times, if not hundreds, and it’s been covered as nauseum in so many easily-accessible English resources).

Comment: I note [your comment in that question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/462261/i-or-me-at-the-end-of-a-list#comment1115253_462261): *"Myself was an attendee"? Pretty clear the right form is "I."* Is your concern about the dupe, or about expressing your strong (but possibly unorthodox) view on the correct solution?

Answer (score 6):

This question has been answered numerous times. A good starting point for researching what would be the best older question to link this one to is this search: [[personal-pronouns] i me](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bpersonal-pronouns%5D+i+me)

The older question it's been linked to isn't exactly the same -- the older one is put as a question about word order. But nohat's answer does answer the newer question because it was very helpfully written to cover more than just what was asked.

Another good existing answer also by nohat is this one: ["Who wants ice-cream?" — Should I say "(not) I" or "(not) me"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4556/who-wants-ice-cream-should-i-say-not-i-or-not-me/4655#4655)

Answer (score 2):

If the question is a duplicate of one or more different questions (in this case it looks like a duplicate of this [one](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/1047/191178)), then the best fix is to get the attention of either a moderator or (if any exist) a matching gold tag badge holder to change the [duplicate list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291824/323179). This can be done any number of ways: chat, flags, meta, comments (but only if they've left a comment on the question), etc. Flags or meta are usually preferred.

Because it might take some time for the change to happen, it doesn't hurt to leave a comment pointing to the correct duplicate.

---

If there's no duplicate and you think the question should be reopened, you can cast a reopen vote when you have the privilege to do so. Until then, a good course of action might be to edit the question, if you can improve it. Sometimes a change of wording can make the difference.

---

For questions that would likely be closed anyway (for another reason) I generally leave instructions for the author on how to improve the question so it can be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that both of these are bad duplicate targets. (I would immodestly suggest [When do I use "I" instead of "me?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/313/when-do-i-use-i-instead-of-me), which I posted an answer to, as a better dupe target for this question.)

The problem is that the "Should I put myself last?" question, although explicitly about word order and not about case from the beginning (the first version said "***regardless of the "me"/"I" usage***"), attracted a number of answers about case. For example, nohat's answer is almost entirely about "and me" vs. "and I", and only addresses the actual question in the final paragraph.

Furthermore, the question was later edited to have the misleading title ""My friends and I" vs. "My friends and me" vs. "Me and my friends", and many questions about "me" vs. "I" were subsequently marked as duplicates of it.

The end result is that the question has become somewhat established as a "dupe target" for questions about "me" vs. "I".

The "who wants ice cream" question is also a favorite dupe target for any kinds of questions about case for some reason.

---

I agree that links to these two questions don't actually suffice to answer any and all questions about the use of "me" vs. "I".

No offense to nohat, but his answers to these two questions were posted very early on in the site, and they don't have any citations or discussion of complicating factors, alternative analyses, or terminological issues. 
A rule like

> Generally speaking, in English, accusative (also known as “objective”) pronouns (like me) are the “default” form. That is, unless there is a specific syntactic rule requiring use of a different case, such as nominative (I), genitive (my/mine), or reflexive/intensive (myself), in English you use the accusative case

doesn't actually answer any questions about specific constructions, because it doesn't tell you whether there is any "specific syntactic rule" requiring the use of some other case in whatever context--e.g. after "and", or after "is". Because any particular grammatical context may have a different pattern of case usage, it makes sense to have separate questions about different contexts.